# Linq-To-Sql Method Not Supported?

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

I'm using a query that tries to find a matching unique identifier (guid) such as

```
var myUsers = from u in table
              where u.UniqueIdentifierId == MyClass.GetCurrentUserId()
              select u;
```

This throws the Method Not Supported error for my custom function. I recoded it to do this

```
string guid = MyClass.GetCurrentUserId().ToString();

where u.UniqueIdentifierId.ToString() == guid
```

And this works. I want to know if there are any other work arounds that do not require creating a temporary variable. Thanks.

Comment: post your peusdo code for GetCurrentUserId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call it in the query, because LINQ to SQL can't translate this. It tries to transform this in a SQL call. What you must do is call this method outside of the LINQ query, as follows:

```
var guid = MyClass.GetCurrentUserId();

var myUsers = 
    from u in table
    where u.UniqueIdentifierId == guid
    select u;
```

Comment: This is correct but it still requires the temporary variable. I am looking for any alternatives. Apparently there are no other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try?

```
var myUsers = from u in table
          where u.UniqueIdentifierId == MyClass.GetCurrentUserId().ToString()
          select u;
```

This would force LINQ to SQL to use string comparison(which is why the second one worked)

Comment: To be clear, it is the method call -- not the string comparison that is the issue.